Are wired, interconnected smoke detectors using 14ga conductors considered an "Non-power-limited Fire Alarm System" in the language of the 2023 NEC?
Am I required to comply with the NEC rules regarding "fire alarm systems" for a residential smoke detector?
Rules such as a red, dedicated circuit breaker labeled "fire alarm system" that isn't AFI/GFI?

Not sure I'd use such heavy wire, lest it be mistaken for AC mains.

Typical residential wired smoke detectors actually run AC between the detectors and a power source, which unless instructions specify otherwise means using 14 AWG (15A circuit) or 12 AWG (15 or 20A circuit).

No, but this requires looking at NFPA 72 to figure out
The NEC defines fire alarm circuits as being involved with a fire alarm system, but doesn't define what a "fire alarm system" is, so we have to look to the fire alarm code, aka NFPA 72, for that definition.
As it turns out, the NFPA 72 definition of a fire alarm system (in 3.3.118, for those playing along at home), does not include smoke alarms, which are defined separately.  So, feel free to hang the smoke alarms off, say, a hall light circuit (which is a better idea anyway because then you'll know if the breaker trips).
